# No password to log out of find my iphone, no i cloud setting options

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, activation-lock

My friend lost his i phone 6, then found it a year later. Since he has got a new phone and started fresh with a new apple id and password. He gave me that phone to use but i cannot sign out of his find my iphone and he does not remember the password. Online it says i can reset and all that starting by using icloud setting. I dont even have i cloud settings as an option and a recovery account on his part is impossible until he is back in the states. Is there a way to get this logged out andphone reset so i can then log into my accounts?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82606/discussion-on-question-by-johnse-dejulio-no-password-to-log-out-of-find-my-iphon).

Answer (score 2):

Your friend needs to pick the easiest of these to accomplish as your friend:

1. Provide proof they were the first purchaser to Apple and get it unlocked. (Or let you know who purchased it originally). When I’ve done this it’s with my business card showing I am and IT Manager for the company matching the purchase order. When I’ve seen this done personally, they looked up the receipt or people provide a copy of the receipt and a drivers license matching the name on the receipt in person at the store.
2. Recover access to the account with the forgotten password https://iforgot.apple.com .
3. Apologize for giving you a locked phone.
4. Encourage you to learn how to open and desolder and break the encryption chain after you consider if educational and research is justified and it’s not theft or breaking into someone else’s property.

All of these seem super helpful for moving you forward.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately he isn't the most helpful and i am not tech savy i just want this to work

Comment: Without access to an apple store how do i provide proof that he or his mom was the first purchaser

Comment: @JohnseDeJulio You can not. He or his mother have to appear.

Comment: @JohnseDeJulio See my edit, he or his mom would have to be at the store with a form of ID the staff accepts generally. This has nothing to do with being tech savvy. This is all about being people savvy, compassionate and working together.

Comment: @bmike I think this is most clever scam to get info how to unlock a phone that is not theirs.

Comment: If it’s a scam, it’s certainly not clever and won’t work and my answer will help others know they can’t easily scam and will help people who legitimately qualify for an unlock. As I see it, the answer works and is helpful whether or not we assume positive intent from the OP. Thus surely could be a plea to steal - it’s possible anyone using this site could do bad with the knowledge they gain, @Buscar웃